# Не работает audio

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет кто может подсказать, не проигрываетса музыка из папки sounds в проекте momentum.  Выдает в консоли 'Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable.'
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас этот файл точно присутствует в папке сайта /stage1-tasks-.../sounds/... ?

Comment: да имеетса в проекте

Comment: А ваш веб-сервер вообще настроен на раздачу файлов из этой папки?

Comment: А как это проверить? Подскажите

Comment: Когда файл отсутствует, появляется ошибка **net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**, а в Вашем случае переводится, как **Медиа-ресурс, указанный атрибутом src или назначенным объектом медиа-провайдера, не подходит.** То бишь, файл есть, но с ним что-то не то.